# Is there a difference in resource use/requirements between Ubuntu and Debian versions of Linux Mint (under the same DE)?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, linux-mint, xfce, resources

I intend to use Linux Mint on a RAM/1GB laptop. I'm used with Xfce and LXDE and I see that both Linux Mint 14 Nadia and Linux Mint Debian have Xfce versions.

Is there a reason to prefer one to the other - from this point of view?

Comment: No there is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may see some slight differences in resource usage from one distro to another when using the same desktop configured in the same way, but it should not be significant.

In other words, as Ulrich said, no there is not a reason to prefer one to the other from this point of view!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an Xfce version really. Xfce, Gnome, KDE etc are just Desktop Environments, they can be installed on any Linux distribution. For example, I use Linux Mint Debian (LMDE) and have Gnome3, Mate, Cinnamon and Xfce installed. I can choose which one I want to run at login.

Many distributions offer versions with a particular DE preinstalled. For example, Ubuntu uses Unity and Kubuntu uses KDE. There is no reason you cannot install KDE on Ubuntu and Unity on Kubuntu. Desktop environments and Window Managers are just another piece of software running on your machine.

The only difference between, for example, LMDE-Xfce and LMDE-Cinnamon is which DE they have installed by default. You can then add as many additional ones as you want.

Comment: "version" was just an expression... all the rest is really clear to me. i used ubuntu for a while with the L/X/K/Unity "variations" or "flavors". i want to get light, and i can with Xfce and especially LXDE. the difference between DE is what's really felt, so it is not a small difference. (above 1GB of RAM and more this is unimportant, but at 1GB LXDE and KDE are different planets). but that is not the point:  I want to know if **with the same DE** (be it Xfce in this case) there's a similar difference in resource-use between a Debian and a Ubuntu based Mint.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be, in theory, any major difference between the distros.  It's 99% the same software when you get up and running - minus any customizations they do.